# Exporting Summary Data to CSV in R

Tags: r

Hello everyone I am working on a script that I would like to export to a CSV file.

Everything is working well with the exception that I would like to add column names and headers for the below data.

For instance variable A is the summary data of fixed income trades in 2017.  I would like Row 1 in the output file to read as such.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  My code is written below.  Thanks in advance!!

```
#SENDS THE RESULTS TO FILE CALLED OUTFILE.TXT WHICH IS OVERWRITTEN EACH TIME SCRIPT IS RUN
sink("outfile.csv")

#SHORT-TERM PRE-REFUNDED TRADE DATA
A = MSRB[which(MSRB$Coupon.Rate >= 2 & MSRB$Year == 2017 & MSRB$Par.Traded >=500 & MSRB$Class == "PRE-REFUNDED"),]
B = MSRB[which(MSRB$Coupon.Rate >= 2 & MSRB$Year == 2017 & MSRB$Par.Traded >=1000 & MSRB$Class == "PRE-REFUNDED"),]
C = MSRB[which(MSRB$Coupon.Rate >= 2 & MSRB$Year == 2018 & MSRB$Par.Traded >=500 & MSRB$Class == "PRE-REFUNDED"),]
D = MSRB[which(MSRB$Coupon.Rate >= 2 & MSRB$Year == 2018 & MSRB$Par.Traded >=1000 & MSRB$Class == "PRE-REFUNDED"),]
E = MSRB[which(MSRB$Coupon.Rate >= 2 & MSRB$Year == 2019 & MSRB$Par.Traded >=500 & MSRB$Class == "PRE-REFUNDED"),]
F = MSRB[which(MSRB$Coupon.Rate >= 2 & MSRB$Year == 2019 & MSRB$Par.Traded >=1000 & MSRB$Class == "PRE-REFUNDED"),]

#SUMMARY OF PRE-REFUNDED DATA 
summary(A$Yield)
summary(B$Yield)
summary(C$Yield)
summary(D$Yield)
summary(E$Yield)
summary(F$Yield)

#END OF OUTPUT FILE
sink()
```

Comment: You should almost certainly assemble your data beforehand into an object and use `write.csv`, or you stand a very good chance of unknowingly introducing issues with your data.

Comment: You want floating text in a data frame which is not a column header ? It is redundant information - you can just name your file : fixed_income_trade_data2017 ? What purpose will the Row 1 containing that text serve?

Comment: I want the text in Row 1 so I can email the summary data concisely in Excel to others.   Without the column text it will be difficult to decipher what's what.